# angular 5 before route from one component to another how to save component form data

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to route one component to another; each component has some form data (`this.formBuilder.group`). while I navigate from one component to another, if I come back to the previous component, the filled data is not restored.

Is that any way to save the data before routing for each component? Is there any lifecycle method is there to detect before leaving the component to save all form data?

```
navigation.ts:
    if(currentNav == "Personal Details"){
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/understand/personal');
    } else if(currentNav == "Contact Details"){
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/understand/contact');
    }

contact.ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.contactDetails = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      mobileNumber: ['', Validators.required],
      secondaryNumber: ['', Validators.required]
   });
  }

personal.ts
    this.personalDetails = this.formBuilder.group({
      country: ['', Validators.required],
      countryOfIssue: ['', Validators.required],
      countryOfBirth: ['', Validators.required]
       });
      }
```

Comment: visit this url for routing events https://angular.io/api/router/Event

You need to store your form data in temp memory. when you come back then you need to read stored data and re-assign to form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persist the data captured in each component in a global service and restore the same when moving back and forth. You can assign the global service object in your constructor or ngOnInit method. Something like below:

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { GlobalService } from'../global.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  homeDetails: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private globalService: GlobalService) {

    this.homeDetails = this.formBuilder.group({
      homename:['', Validators.required]
    });

   }

  ngOnInit() {
      if(this.globalService.homeDetails){
        this.homeDetails = this.globalService.homeDetails;
      }
  }


  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.globalService.homeDetails = this.homeDetails;

  }

}
```

global.service.ts

```
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {
  public homeDetails: FormGroup;
  public aboutDetails: FormGroup;
}
```

You can look at OnDestroy to implement any code before moving to another component.

**Updated**: Code for home.component.ts and global.service.ts as per the stackblitz url

Comment: can u able to share any fiddle example ?

Comment: user3392782: - here i try to create the service, please help to update https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-example-e4y2xm?file=app%2Fglobal.service.ts

Comment: I am unable to save the stackblitz edit. Have updated my answer with the changes needed.

Comment: wow. it work exactly what i expected... thanks a lot, please find my updated sackblits....https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-example-nufsnz?file=app/about/about.component.ts

Comment: like that if i have multiple component, user to fill data. but in the last component.eg. like home, about, contact etc.. lat step if i want to send all data to server side how to maintain all "formGroup" data in one place or what is best to to send all data to server side ?

Comment: You will have to pull the required data from global service and construct the respective request to post. Its pretty standard. Not sure what help you would need.

Comment: I mean from the global service we may have multiple public components related FormGroup data right? How to send all data as single FormGroup or object nested with unique identifier of each FormGroup/Object?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of lifecycle methods, you can probably decide to use CanDeactivate Route Guard on exiting component, which give you ability to add features such as save and cancel. For info try https://v5.angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes.

Comment: hi, can you help to update the same in this stack? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-example-c92hmv?file=app/about/about.component.ts